# Unable to receive push notification in Android using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

In Parse console it shows Delivery report as successful, but onPushReceive is not getting called at all. What am I missing here? any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code. 
Manifest code:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.appname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.appname.PushReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.-->

            <category android:name="com.appname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

PushReceiver class:

```
public class PushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

    Log.v("Push Receive called...", "");


    if (intent == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



}
```

Comment: may be something wrong in your google-services.json

Comment: parse is shut down. you should move to another service.

Comment: @DevendraSingh Ya I know that, this is just a temporary solution for a couple of months.

Comment: look at [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) **step 2**

Comment: google-services.json file looks good only.

Comment: What is in the logcat? Did you set the breakpoint on the method itself? What happened there?

Comment: Method is not getting called.

Comment: Unless you just didn't include them in the code you posted for your manifest, I think you are missing the GCM service to register (set up a token for) the mobile device

Answer (score 2):

Add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

Check the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="com.appname.PushReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.appname.INTERCEPT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here're permissions you should have in your manifest:

```
<!-- Push Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="your_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Here're other stuff you should define in your manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="your_package_name" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
```

With this manifest configuration i can successfully receive pushes from parse.

Comment: Typo: staff --> stuff

Answer (score 2):

**In Addition To The Permissions**

There are a few things that cause Parse to not properly send the push notification. Parse does not do a great job at detailing them, but from what I have experienced with Parse, i can try to shed some light on things that are a not always so obvious.

If you are checking the Parse dashboard and are able to see your device register, that is good. *However,* you need to make sure that there is a deviceToken registered for that device. If there is not, I can almost guarantee that if you check your pushes tab, you will see that the success rate of that push was 0% or unsuccessful.

**Making sure deviceToken is registering**
Other than simply initializing Parse, *please* make sure that the package name of your app matches that name which you use to link with in your Android Manifest. If that is not the case, that is most certainly a cause of not receiving pushes.

**Intializing Parse**

```
    private void initializeParse() {
         Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
         Parse.initialize(this);
         ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Initializing parse with app id: " + getString(R.string.parse_app_id) + " client_key: " + getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
}
```

**Listening For Pushes**

```
public class ParsePluginReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "ParsePluginReceiver";
private static final String RECEIVED_IN_FOREGROUND = "receivedInForeground";
private static int badgeCount = 0;
public static final String FORWARD_EXTRA = "FORWARD_ACTIVITY";


@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    JSONObject pushData = getPushData(intent);

    if (pushData != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "JSON Payload: " + pushData.toString());
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }
}

protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    JSONObject pushData = getPushData(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "JSON Payload: " + pushData.toString());

    if (pushData != null) {
        try {
            super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
 }
```

As reference, Parse Sdk is located here: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide

**Side Note**
Parse is to be deprecated start of next year.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have all these permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="your_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your_package_name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

And you need to add all of these to your Manifest:

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="your_package_name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Just some advise, move on to something such as Firebase. Parse is shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

Checking your installation object with device-token. (maybe you should set senderID)

below seems deprecated. I can't find any where from parse docs now.
try to add following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission
        android:name="com.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

These are needed permissions for old sdk version (maybe older than 1.10).

==============New part====

I have found the push sample code on github.
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/Android

Below is the project which use 1.11.0 sdk(1.13.0 can work,too).
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82261293/Appname.zip

In my experience, some devices have chance that without device token. You should check it have been saved.

Comment: I added these permissions before posting the question. Doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have deviceToken, which must be saved in the DB?

Answer (score -1):

> **Parse will be fully retired.**

I got mail from parse that they are going to retired. So why are you doing that mistakes that is going to expired. Try using gsm or socket that is more lighter.