# Android signed apk doesn't reveived Parse.com push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-play, apk

I'm using Parse.com for my application and everything was working fine in debug mode.
I was well receiving all the notifications.

But now I have generate signed apk and upload it to the store.
I have downloaded my app on my phone and I can't get any notification from Parse.com (even when I'm sending a fake push from parse UI)

Do you know what could be the reason ?

Thanks,

Comment: see is this helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181942/unable-to-receive-push-notification-in-android-using-parse

Comment: No it doesn't help .. I don't knwo why it's working only in debug and not in release !

Comment: Trace 2 part, one is save _Installation successfully, second is check whether DeviceToken is record in this _Installation object.

Comment: If you have multiple Parse-app, the currentInstallation will keep its id. So that you will save failed by Object not found for update.

Comment: In my _Installation class, all deviceToken for android installation are null but I guess it's normal as deviceToken is only used for IOS installation ? One hour ago, I have installed my signed apk using android studio termianl command and I have received all the notifications .. So I have publish it to the google play store and I will see if it works ..